# Remove Unused Using in VS 2012 Premium

Tags: visual-studio, reference, project

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012.

**[Microsoft directions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514115.aspx) states:**

- **Main Menu** - On the **Edit menu**, point to **IntelliSense**, point to **Organize Usings**, and then click **Remove Unused Usings**.

However, there is no option called "Organize Usings" in the "Intelliense" menu on the "Edit" menu-tab.  I can use the context-menu to accomplish this...but that option only appears for a single open code-behind file (when I have it open). Doing so one code-file at-a-time is useless to me in a large project.

Also...

I have looked at other questions for previous version of Visual Studio on this site, and their answers don't work in 2012 Premium.

**So my question is...**

**How can I "Remove Unused Usings" within Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012 across a single project or solution?**

Comment: Not an option, this command only works one file at a time.

Comment: @HansPassant  How unfortunate...thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to write a Visual Studio Extension to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the Macro at this link](http://vihang-shah.blogspot.fr/2011/08/3-reasons-to-remove-unused-using-in.html) that opens all files of your project and remove unused usings. Otherwise [PowerCommands](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands) contains some useful extensions, including one that remove all unused usings (never tested it though).